# Insert double -- in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I have some text which I need to put in an sqlite database. I do not know how to make sqlite accept the double minus in the text because sqlite treats it as a comment.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're putting the string into quotation marks?
Like this:

```
insert into table1 ('Text -- with -- double minus')
```

**EDIT:**

For a multiline string, try something like:

```
insert into table1 ('Text' + char(13) + char(10) + '-- with double minus')
```

Comment: It's a multiline text and one of the lines has -- at the beginning. Once I remove the line with the -- it works fine.

Comment: Does it work for you without the double minus? I didn't know you could use multiline strings in an SQL query. Anyway I edited the answer, does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put text directly inside SQL INSERT statements; [it causes problems](http://xkcd.com/327/) if you're not careful.

The preferred approach is to use parameterized queries.  That way you don't need to deal with escaping strings.

In the C API, use the [sqlite3_bind_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) family of functions.

In the Python sqlite3 module, pass the parameters as a separate argument to `execute`.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> db.execute("CREATE TABLE Table1 (A TEXT, B TEXT)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xe2fa80>
>>> dbl_minus = 'Text -- with -- double minus'
>>> multiline = 'Text\nwith\nline\nbreaks'
>>> db.execute("INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (?, ?)", (dbl_minus, multiline))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0xe2fb30>
>>> db.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1").fetchall()
[('Text -- with -- double minus', 'Text\nwith\nline\nbreaks')]
```